# indexOf(model.object) instead of indexOf(model) not working as intended

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to list the users in a store. This is 100% working when I use the user model below.

```
// Model
store : { type: Array },
```

Then there's radio buttons of each store.

```
<!-- Button for 'all' users -->
<label class="btn-l33t" ng-model="radio.model" btn-radio="allstores">
  {{global.user.company || 'null'}}
</label>

<!-- Button that filters users by store. 100% working -->
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="store in global.user.store">
    <label class="btn-l33t" ng-model="radio.model" btn-radio="store">
     {{store}}
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Finally there's the table of users

```
<!-- Show user if store is in user.store -->
<!-- 100% working -->
<tr ng-show="user.store.indexOf(radio.model) != -1 || radio.model === allstores" data-ng-repeat="user in users">
```

So now I changed my model. The stores array takes an object so we can have sections within stores.

```
store: {
  type: Array,
  thing: {
      name: String,
      section: Array,
  }
},
```

This list of users works fine, but the table of users won't filter any more. Checking a radio button does nothing. I updated the radio buttons and they show the store name & section perfectly.

```
<label class="btn-l33t" ng-model="radio.model" btn-radio="allstores">
  {{global.user.company || 'null'}}
</label>

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="store in global.user.store">
    <label class="btn-l33t" ng-model="radio.model" btn-radio="store">
      {{store.name}} <!-- changed {{store}} to {{store.name}} -->
      <!-- for some reason it's store.name and not store.thing.name -->
    </label>
    <!-- added sections. This is working fine -->
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="section in store.section" >
        <label class="btn-l33t" ng-model="radio.model2" btn-radio="section">
          {{section}}
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Where I run into a problem is the table listing users. Not sure what to put here to fix it.

```
<tr ng-show="user.store.thing.name.indexOf(radio.model.name) != -1 || radio.model === null" data-ng-repeat="user in users">
```

Edit/Update: This is how I add stores:

```
var obj ={ 
   name: $scope.datStore.name, 
   section: ["grocery","utensils"]
}
user3[0].store.push(obj);
```

Maybe this is why stores.name works and it's not stores.thing.name. But then shouldn't the model be updated? Model's accepting this, for some reason.

Comment: Hi! Could you please have a look at my answer and let me know if that solves your question and/or if you need more help. If my answer does solve your question, could you please mark it as accepted? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your latest update your `store` has this structure:

```
store: [
        {name:'name1', section:['section1', 'section2']}, 
        {name:'name2', section:['section3', 'section4']}
       ]
```

Therefore I think that what you want to do is this:

```
<tr ng-show="!radio.model || (user.store|filter : {name : radio.model.name}).length > 0" data-ng-repeat="user in users">
```

Comment: You're an amazing person. Thank you for fixing my problem and saving me HOURS of research and debugging. This is so perfect. I can't thank you enough!